# How do I install specific version of Nginx on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I've got an Ubuntu 14.04 webserver, and I'd like to install a specific major version of Nginx on it. This means that if I install Nginx 1.8, I do not want Ubuntu to upgrade to 1.9 at any point. However, minor version upgrades are OK (1.8.1 to 1.8.2).

I've found the PPA `nginx/stable`, but isn't someone maintaining a repository where I can choose the actual version to install? This would be similar to the Ubuntu official package, but just a newer major version.

I consider this to be an essential requirement in order to be able to maintain stable environments where (a) I can guarantee a specific version and (b) critical software not suddenly just jumps a major version up and consequently breaks due to e.g. non-compatibility with configuration files.

Comment: slightly off topic, http://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package

Answer (score 8):

Install the specific version from [nginx ppa](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/)

```
sudo apt-get install nginx=1.8.*
```

And stay there

```
sudo apt-mark hold nginx=1.8.*
```

although you could just stick with 'stable' and trust the package maintainers.

```
sudo -s
nginx=stable # use nginx=development for latest development version
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/$nginx/ubuntu lucid main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-$nginx-lucid.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C300EE8C
apt-get update
apt-get install nginx
```

[how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

Comment: Thanks! The Launchpad PPA does not say anything about version specific packages, does it? I could only see "community", "stable", "mainline" and "nightly".

Comment: stick with stable, which is 1.8 per nginx's site, it doesn't say a specific version cause that could change down the road.

Comment: But what happens when 1.9 becomes stable, then I suddenly find myself having a new major version on my systems?

Comment: Are you auto-updating your systems without user intervention? This is the purpose of programs like Ansible, but you you wouldn't update without checking this information first, if you want to ENSURE you don't go to 1.9, use the apt-mark function.

Comment: If I could install a specific major version, then I could be relatively sure that new minor versions would still be OK after updates. If I want to upgrade from 1.8 to 1.9, I want that to be a planned decision I make - and not a decision I have to make based on what the next update gives me. Doesn't that make sense?

Comment: Read https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-8-and-1-9-released/

Comment: It describes version differences. I tried "sudo apt-get install nginx-1.8*", which does not work by the way?

Comment: Use equal sign instead... `sudo apt-get install nginx=1.9*`

Answer (score 2):

This will be really helpful for someone. Exact line :

sudo apt-get install nginx=1.16.0-1~xenial

or

sudo apt-get install nginx=1.18.0-1~xenial

How to get the exact name? check this site, for example for nginx :[https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/16.04/nginx-amd64/nginx_1.16.1-1~xenial_amd64.deb.html](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/16.04/nginx-amd64/nginx_1.16.1-1%7Exenial_amd64.deb.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a version of Nginx (or any tools/apps) different than the one in the official repsoitory the best way is to download the tarball and self-compilation.

I don't think this the best place to ask if any of launchpad repo is maintained or not. Best is to ask this question to the repository owners and they will tell you if either maintained regularly or not.

However, it not a rocket science, so just compile it yourself from source.

Comment: Yes, I know this is an option but to be honest if there is a ready made repository which offers me what I need then I'd be happy to go with that :-)